# Is there any connection between imperative programming and the Von Neumann architecture?

Tags: programming-paradigms

I have ran into a wall with this question in the exercise my teacher gave me, is there any actual connetion between the Von Neumann architecture and imperative programming ?

I have tried googling and finding questions similar to this, but I couldn't find anything, and the one question that I have found actually said that there shouldn't be any connection between the Von Neumann architecture and programming paradigms.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to StackExchange, so if I'm breaking any rules please do tell me :)

Comment: Looks a Good Question (if on your instructor's behalf). There is finding out what others think/present. There's trying to create knowledge yourself: What is the essence of *Imperative Programming*, of a program coded imperatively; what discriminates the *von Neumann architecture*, a computer device manufactured in adherence from one that is not? Having both spelled out succinctly should help assess *actual* relations - if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

von Neumann architecture is memory for data and instructions and a CPU that fetches and executes instructions one after the other. That is intrinsecally imperative. Compare with functional programming (define functions that call among themselves) or logic programming (search for a solution  to a set of logic statements). Other paradigms like OOP are more or less orthogonal to the above.